# If S is a subspace, then the intersection of S and S⊥ is the zero subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

If S is a subspace, then the intersection of S and S⊥ is the zero subspace.
Is this true or false? I do not quite understand what this statement means. What is the "intersection"? How do you prove this is right or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The intersection of two subspaces is their intersection as a set! For example, when you intersect two lines passing through the origin (which are one-dimensional subspaces), you get a point (which is a zero-dimensional subspace) (passing through the origin is important, otherwise we are into the field of affine transformations, where the above doesn't hold true).

Now you understand what intersection means. All you have to prove is that if there is any element $x$ that is both in $S$ and in $S_\perp$, then $x=0$! That will show that the intersection consists only of zero, so that the intersection is the zero subspace.

For this, note that by definition of $S_{\perp}$, every element of $S_{\perp}$ is orthogonal, or has zero inner product with every element of $S$. If we assume that $x$ is in both $S$ and $S_{\perp}$, then $x$ must be orthogonal to itself i.e. it's inner product with itself is zero. But $\langle x,x\rangle = 0 \implies x=0$! Hence, $x$ can only be $0$, and the intersection of $S$ and $S_{\perp}$ is the zero subspace. Please ask if any doubts persist.